problema con google OAuth en laravel 8 al subirlo a un servidor plesk
Tengo un login en laravel 8 en el cual ocupo autenticación por google, en mi localhost funciona bien pero al subirlo a mi servidor plesk me marca un error 403 Forbidden al intentan loguearme con mi correo, ya configuré los URI de redireccionamiento autorizados en mi google cloud y no funciona.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
